# Is it possible to hide androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, malware, apk

I heard from someone today that androidmanifest.xml is hidden by new malware. I couldn't find anything about this on the internet. Is it possible?

Comment: Depending on the meaning of "hidden", i.e. is it only the content or the file itself, I found these: [GitHub Apktool -  \[BUG\] Malware corrupted the android manifest and other files.](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2859), [Blogspot: (Not only) Android malware analysis - Having fun with AndroidManifest.xml
](https://maldr0id.blogspot.com/2014/09/having-fun-with-androidmanifestxml.html)

Comment: I heard this in an interview. They said that new mobile malware can work without androidmanifest.xml. I was surprised. I said that I didn't have such knowledge because I had never heard of such a thing before and it didn't make sense. Maybe I misunderstood their question.